# How to make a custom post type read-only for a user role?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Here is my post type:

```
register_post_type('accident', array(
'labels'             => array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Accidents', 'post type general name', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Accident', 'post type singular name', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Accidents', 'admin menu', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Accident', 'add new on admin bar', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'accident', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Accident', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Accident', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Accident', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Accident', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Accidents', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Accidents', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Accidents:', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No accidents found.', 'twentyfifteen-child' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No accidents found in Trash.', 'twentyfifteen-child' )
),
'public'             => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui'            => true,
'show_in_menu'       => true,
'query_var'          => true,
'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'accidents'),
'capability_type'    => 'accident',
'capabilities' => array(
    'publish_posts' => 'publish_accidents',
    'edit_posts' => 'edit_accidents',
    'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_accidents',
    'delete_posts' => 'delete_accidents',
    'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_accidents',
    'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_accidents',
    'edit_post' => 'edit_accident',
    'delete_post' => 'delete_accident',
    'read_post' => 'read_accident'
),
'map_meta_cap'       => true,
'has_archive'        => false,
'hierarchical'       => false,
'supports'           => array('title', 'editor')
));
```

What I am trying to achieve is showing the "Accidents" button on admin menu, which shows the accidents listing only - no edit, delete, add new functionalities. But it doesn't appear. I tried adding the "read_accident" and "read_accidents" capabilities to the user role (which now has only the "read" capability), but the button still doesn't show. Is this even possible to do natively?

Answer (score 0):

The `read` capability is for the frontend, so it doesn't appear on the admin menu.

If you want still to show the list in the admin to the specific role users, you could grant them the `edit_accidents` capability and then block it via code:

```
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', function() {
    global $typenow;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $typenow === 'accident' && in_array('your_user_role', $user->roles) )
        wp_die(__('Sorry, not for you.', 'your-textdomain'), 403);
} );
```

Comment: There are also ways to hide the `Add New` buttons